# PrintStream.println() behavior -- Java / Python / Any Language

Tags: java, python

I think I'm having a little doubt with the concept of `println()` method.

I tried the following code:

```
Object one = 1;
System.out.println(one);

one = "String";
System.out.println(one);

one = null;

System.out.println(one.toString()); // To explicitly throw an Exception
```

The expected output is and indeed I get this sometimes:

```
1
String
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:18) <5 internal calls>
```

However running multiple times, we can see see the following outputs, as well:

```
1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:18) <5 internal calls>
String
```

or

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:18) <5 internal calls>
1
String
```

Then, I thought of performing similar operation in Python. Below is the snippet:

```
var = 'Hello';
print var;
var = 6;
print var;
del var;
print var;
```

And yes, the similar behavior. The traceback message output preference cannot be determined. Sometimes, its printed at the top, sometimes in the middle or sometimes at the bottom.

I think it must be something related to `synchronized` buffer output. Not sure, it could be.

Can anyone help me out in getting this concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact you have two output streams `System.out` and `System.err` and they are not co-ordinated or always in order.

You can do

```
Object one = 1;
System.err.println(one);

Object one = "String";
System.err.println(one);

one = null;

System.out.println(one.toString());
```

or

```
Object one = 1;
System.out.println(one);

Object one = "String";
System.out.println(one);

one = null;

try {
    System.out.println(one.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

What you should do is use a logger. The logger will be configured to write everything to either System.out or System.err so you will get a predictable out put.

> I think it must be something related to synchronized buffer output.

Both `System.out` and `System.err` are synchronized. They don't use the same lock as they are not the same object, though this wouldn't matter because the two streams they write to can be read in any order.

Comment: Ok..  But does it jump from `out` stream to `err` stream? I explicitly used `System.out.println`.

Comment: Does applying `try catch` block prevents it going from `out` stream to `err` stream?

Comment: @cprakashagr `out` and `err` are two separate streams, one doesn't jump to the other. They are both displayed on the console. I can see you use `System.out.println` can you see I used `System.err.println` in my first example.

Comment: @cprakashagr try/catch(Exception) catches Exceptions. By catching the exception you prevent it being displayed by the default uncaught exception handler which writes it to the console using `System,err` In this case I wrote it to System.out.  This way all the output goes to the same stream so the resulting order of output is predictable.